# How do I get a culture specific short date string?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want short date with culture format. I got date with the culture but also want only date, not a time. I am using `IValueConverter` for that.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var item = (DateTime)value;

    if (item != null)
    {
        return item.ToString(culture);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using IValueConverter when all you need is format DateTime to a particular format?

Comment: Do you mean `ToShortDateString` is not working for you ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta yes it is not working with cultured date time.

Comment: Is this what you want? `return item.ToString("d", culture);`

Comment: @LPL yes this is correct solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is also right but I found the solution thanks.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var item = (DateTime)value;
    if (item != null)
    {
        return item.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, culture);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 23):

This will give you based on current culture, if you want a specific culture that can be done too...

```
string format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
String Date = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
```